# how to use predict()

Tags: r, linear-regression, poisson

Want to predict a value but this is clearly not the solution. I am doing a multiple choice test and 0.304... is not an answer.How to use predict() correctly?

```
library(glm2)
data(crabs)
fit= glm(Satellites~Width,data=crabs, family="poisson")
plot(Satellites~Width,data=crabs)
abline(fit)
predict(fit, newdata=data.frame(Width=c(22)))
1 
0.3042347
```

Comment: What about this is wrong?

Comment: I don't think the value is correct since I am doing a multiple choice thest and 0.304.. is not an answer.

Comment: Ummm... `22 * fit$coef[2] + fit$coef[1]` gives what you have posted. It is right. But clearly, it is not what you expected!

Comment: Value you got with predict() is log() of expected value because you made a Poisson regression. Just make exp(value) to get the same scale as original values.

Comment: Wow how can I imagine that! @DidzisElferts you are right! It fits

Comment: Should be an answer! @DidzisElferts

Comment: @Roo yes this shouls be an answer bu I suggest that you modify a little bit your question...to add what you said in the comments for example.

Comment: @Roo ! no it looks as a "good" question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Function `predict()` for Poisson regression (for GLM in general) by default will calculate the values *on the scale of the linear predictors*, i.e. the log scale in this case (see help file for `predict.glm`).

```
predict(fit, newdata=data.frame(Width=c(22)))
        1 
0.3042347
```

To get the predicted values *on the scale of the response variable*, you should add argument `type="response"` to function `predict()`.

```
predict(fit, newdata=data.frame(Width=c(22)),type="response")
       1 
1.355587
```

Comment: +1!`preidct` looks sometimes clunky to use! but it is really a great workhorse!

Comment: I am not sure what the scale linear predictors have to do with log() though... even more confused.

Comment: You fitted a poisson model.  As `?poisson` will tell you, the default link function of the Poisson is the log (that shows up as `poisson(link = "log")` in the help file). "on the scale of the linear predictor" means on the log scale in this context.  If this is totally unfamiliar to you, it might be helpful to do some more reading about Poisson GLMs ...

Comment: @Roo, Venables & Ripley's MASS book has an entire chapter explaining this:   http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Applied-Statistics-W-N-Venables/dp/0387954570